# Kentico: How to show blog posts from all categories but one?

Tags: filter, categories, kentico

Our website is built on Kentico V8. We are currently redesigning our homepage. We have a repeater that shows the 4 most recent blog posts. These posts are in 5 different categories. There is one category that we do not want to show up on the homepage, but all the rest of the categories should. So,

- Cat 1 - yes
- Cat 2 - yes
- Cat 3 - yes
- Cat 4 - yes
- Cat 5 - NO

Is there a where condition or some other method that can filter out that one category?

Comment: Hi there! :) I would recommend considering re-writing your title and intro sentence to reflect your actual question: is there a where condition or some other method to filter in a Kentico repeater. It may help attract more views and answers to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You an use the repeater's WHERE condition and use e.g.: `DocumentID NOT IN (Select DocumentID FROM CMS_DocumentCategory WHERE CategoryID = 1)` This will exclude the pages form the category with ID=1. You may need to check the category ID in CMS_Category DB table.

Comment: That's it! Thank you so much!